# Jooq not able to log SQL queries

Tags: java, logging, log4j, jooq

I am using Jooq along with JAX-RS to create a REST API.
I have the following dependencies in my maven pom file `log4j 1.2.7` and `jooq 3.9.4` 
I have put the `log4j.properties` file in resources folder. Here are the contents of the file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/home/ps06756/log4j-application.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Still, Jooq is not logging the SQL statemennts being executed. 
How should I correct this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have `logback` or `slf4j` on your classpath as that is the first logger the [`JooqLogger`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ/src/main/java/org/jooq/tools/JooqLogger.java#L95) tries to find on the classpath.
If it fails it tries `log4j` and after that it falls to `java.util.logger`.

When it does find `logback` or `slf4j` but you don't have any configuration you will not see anything being logged.